# My changes for .py files not working on Django

Tags: python, django, wsgi

I have a Django app on a linux server, I made some changes and not reflected, I think I need restart the app but,

When I use this command `python manage.py runserver` for restart app, I getting this response:

`Non-ASCII character '\xc9' in file /home/project/settings.py on line 140, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

therefore, I think need update `settings.py` with

```
#! /usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
```

this codes, but my changes not reflected on server again.

How can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your settings file? At least somewhere around line 140

Comment: Hocam tesekkur ederim cevabiniz icin, here is my 140. line:  `('az', _('Azərbaycan')),`